# Cateye Computer Probe Wire Repair

Tags: repair, bike-computer

I snagged the wire on my Cateye Mity 8 computer on the rack the other day and broke it mid wire.  I'm going to fix it by splicing them back together.  I'm worried about effects of getting the wires crossed.  I'm going to take some care not to cross them, but if I do, will it cause problems?  What readings should I get from it with a multi-meter?

Comment: It's worth noting a new one, with zip ties and everything, is around $10: https://www.google.com/search?q=cateye+mity+8+mounting+kit&safe=off&espv=2&biw=944&bih=927&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=PXidVfigGsbboASXiLSgBg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAA&dpr=1#q=cateye+mity+8+mounting+kit&safe=off&tbs=vw:l,p_ord:p&tbm=shop&spd=9478171537997354999.

Comment: Yeah, but cutting off a few inches of cable around the break point and splicing the cable together is well under 10 dollars.

Comment: I would guess that the two wires have different colored insulation.

Comment: Look *very carefully* at the wire.  It's hardly ever the case that there is not some identifying mark (often a thin rib on the jacket) marking one conductor vs the other.  Or one conductor may be silver, the other copper.  Or, as Carl suggests, they may have different color inner insulators.

Comment: I did order a replacement and it was over $15 form Niagara.  However I was able to splice the broken one without determining which wire was what.  I still count tell the difference.  I could have counted strands but there was only five in each side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do the magnet sensing:

1. [Reed switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch) (a switch which physically closes with a magnetic field). If you swap the two wires, the sensor will work fine (i.e. it doesn't matter). You can test for this using the continuity tester mode of your multimeter (you'll have continuity if the magnet is near the sensor, and open circuit with the magnet far away).
2. [Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) sensor (Generally, there are 3 wires on here: Vdd, ground and the output of the sensor). There are 3!=6 ways you can wire it (so 5 ways to mess it up). Most likely, you won't get a reading from the sensor until you get it right if you don't hook it up correctly. As noted by Chris H, if you have a Hall effect sensor, chances are the wires will be color coded so you'll figure out Vdd and ground, and the remainder is output. Your multimeter won't really help you here.
3. An [inductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor) (basically, a coil of wire). If you swap the two wires, the sensor would work fine (it'd be equivalent to moving the sensor to the other side of the bike, i.e. it doesn't matter). Your multimeter will show continuity always, but if you have a LCR meter, you can check the inductance. If you measure resistance,  you should see a few ohms.

So, basically, if you have 2 wires, chances are you can swap them without worrying and the thing should work. If you have 3, maybe you'll have to disassemble the sensor, figure out which sensor is in there and then look up the pinout (or guess based on color coding of the wires).

There are a few more types of magnetic switches, but they're unlikely to occur in this application.

Comment: You'd have to be really unlucky to have a hall sensor *and* no colour coding.  Anyway zooming right in to the manual for that model shows what looks like figure-of-8 cable, i.e. probably 2 wires (though it *could* still be like headphone wire).

Comment: It's happened before on other products, esp. now electronics are considered disposable.

Comment: that's true, but it does make assembly harder so seems to be rare.

Comment: @ChrisH It is a 2 wire setup.  However, there is no markings on the wire to suggest which goes to which, so I have to stare at the break for a while to figure it out.  I can't imagine this being a reed switch though due to the shear number of times it would get activated, but I have noticed a tick when near it.  Either way, I have a go at it tonight.

Comment: Even a cheap reed switch would work for tens of thousands of miles (esp. in low voltage+current applications like this one) -- you're much more likely to destroy the cable or something else before the switch goes (and it is known Garmin among others use reed switches in some of their models). If you hear a tick near it, it is a reed switch.

Comment: You can re-connect the two wires any way you want. The sensor is a switch that is closed by the passing magnet. So if you connect the ends from the sensor to an Ohm-meter the reading should be (close to) 0 Ohm with the magnet next to the sensor and next to infinite with the magnet away. On the other hand shorting the wires from the computer on-off very rapidly will give a speed and distance reading.

Comment: @Carel - Thanks. That was my intention to state in the answer (I guess "nothing happens" could be interpreted as the thing won't work).

Comment: @batman, splicing it fixed it just fine.  I still couldn't find a marking for which wire is which.

Answer (score 1):

Confirming that for my Cateye Velo 7, the sensor is a Reed switch, which is activated by the wheel magnet passing.

I couldn't understand where the third wire was, since I'd been doing cadence monitoring via a hall sensor but this gave me a direction. I just need to play around with the in-circuit resistance. When I connected 3 volts to the pads and activated the Reed switch, it was a short circuit. I was afraid I destroyed the Reed switch. There must be some resistance inside the computer because there is nothing on the outside. (I'm adapting the cateye sensor and cable to my home grown cadence tracker.)

Comment: But what is the answer to the question?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. This site does not operate like a typical forum. It operates on a Q&A basis. It's not clear that this post answers the OP's question about what happens if the wires get crossed and how to tell if that happens. Please edit your answer to more clearly address the question. See our [help pages](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help) or take our [tour] for more information about how the site works.